# Are questions about paper choice on-topic?

Tags: support, on-topic-definition

I'm considering to change the paper I used for printing to another one with slightly different grammage (grams per square meter) and not sure whether this is a right choice.

Would asking a question about paper selection be okay here? If not which other SE site would be okay?

Comment: My rule of thumb for things like this is: what kind of person's professional expertise is most relevant? If it's about paper for a professional print run or something like screen printing or studio large-format printers, then that's something print designers would know about and is relevant to their work. If it's about paper for an office laser or regular desktop inkjet, that's more of a question for tech support types and so maybe is better asked at http://superuser.com (I *think* they do hardware questions, can't remember - check!). Just my opinion

Answer (score 5):

Choice of paper stock can make or break the final result of a design, so I'd have to say it's on topic.

Answer (score 4):

I'd sway to the **yes** side.

I agree with user568458's comment that questions on related to commercial printing or silkscreening could be beneficial.

However, I'd also say that Photographers, designers,and artists often print to their own high-end printers to create prints for sale. Stock used in this workflow would equally be on topic to me.

In addition, there are many small shops running equipment like oversized printers or Fiery Rips and that would also make the questions on topic to me.

But.... "what paper she we use in the office printer" would be off-topic.